# Can I answer relatively old questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

Some questions may not be on the first few pages anymore but I still want to answer them. Maybe I think that I know an answer to them.

Is that OK as per site rules? Can I answer "old" questions that do not have any answers or a best answer yet?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Please feel free to answer any and all questions on the site.  The questions that appear on the first few pages are just the ones that happen to have been modified recently, they don't affect whether you can answer them.

Comment: In fact, if a question has been unanswered for a long time, that's all the more reason to try to answer it.  I for one have asked tons of questions long ago that I'm still eagerly awaiting answers on.

Comment: It will be great if you can post answers on old questions, not only that will bump the question up in the queue but it will also help future visitors who are looking for a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not just 'OK', it's actually recommended.

> Answering old questions has many pros.
>
> - It will get bumped to the frontpage. Getting more views and your answer possibly getting upvotes
> - **You answer the question for anyone who comes later with the exact same question.**
> - You show others the question, who might answer it.
> - You might get a badge for answering an old question
> - The user (if still active) will get a notification of new answers to his question

<sup>(From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23999/187039) to [Does it make sense to answer old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23996/187039))</sup>